# Intuitively Understanding Android Tasks

Tags: android, architecture

[Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) is the definitive resource for understanding the **mechanism** involving tasks and their interaction with the Back button. In an early paragraph:

> A task is a collection of activities
>   that users interact with when
>   performing a certain job. The
>   activities are arranged in a stack
>   (the "back stack"), in the order in
>   which each activity is opened.

Tasks are then explained in terms of the home screen and how it launches processes. This makes sense. I'm curious, however: **What should determine the use of multiple tasks in "user" applications?**

I'm interested in a intuitive understanding or heuristic guiding task usage rather than simply trying to achieve specific orderings of activities on the back stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A task is a group of components that work coherently together to fulfill a purpose for the user (not necessarily a very specific purpose, but a purpose nonetheless).  It's what the user sees as an application.

A music player exists to allow the user to manage and play songs.  It may include various activities that display album/artist/song metadata, control playback, organize playlists, etc.  It may also include services that implement the playback and that watch for new songs.  The user doesn't know what an activity and a service are; he or she only knows that this series of screens lets him or her manage and play songs.

The activities in a task don't need to belong to the same 'application' from a development standpoint.  If the music player task allows users to link an image to a song, then it might launch an image gallery activity or the camera activity.  Since the new activity is still working toward the purpose of managing songs, it's still part of the same task.

On the other hand, if the user completely breaks out of the task's purpose, it might be time to start a different task.  For example, if you launch a web browser to view the artist's website, the user is now doing something different.  The user probably doesn't associate web browsing with managing and playing songs, so this should probably be a different task.

Comment: Are you saying that a task forms a sort of 'application' from the user's point of view, which may not from a single <application/> ?

Comment: @Matthew: Right.  The task may pull activities from various packages, but the activities all work together to accomplish the task's purpose.  From the user's perspective, it's the closest Android equivalent to a desktop application.

Comment: Judging from your profile, I should be asking you questions, not the other way around.  Still the Activity/Task idea was something I didn't really grasp until after reading it, puzzling over it, getting well into an introductory Android book (which involved making and transitioning between several activities), and re-reading about tasks.

Answer (score -1):

I think a task in that given context is sort of a workflow. Take email. Writing a new email may consist of
first filling in recipients and then in the next activity selecting recipients and clicking on send finally sends the email off.
Another task could be selecting multiple emails and then deleting all in one go.

In practice what you often find is an `AsyncTask` which is basically doing work in background which otherwise would block the UI thread and make the app non-responsive.

Comment: I'm not sure AsyncTask is a Task in the Activity/Back-stack sense.